# Is it possible to save a gpx on Oruxmaps

Tags: gpx, oruxmaps

I'm using the feature "Find route" in Oruxmaps, which will compute off line a track with GraphHopper.

Thing is I cannot find a way to save it as gpx. Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible. Touch the first icon of the route created from Graphhopper or BRouter. A menu with options will appear. Choose the floppy icon .
The route will be saved in Tracklogs.
If the path does not show the first and last wp, you must look in the global configuration and activate this option.

Comment: Yep, it works ! Hard to find this one !